# SSPI negotiation failed with WtrustChannelFactory

Tags: windows, single-sign-on, adfs, sspi

This one has me for a while now, I am trying to build a console app that can call a .net web/wcf service  SP, the first leg is to get a token from the idP (ADFS4.0) the pasted code was working fine for a whole day, at some point it stopped working with the following error:

`SOAP security negotiation with 'https://adfs.domain.in/adfs/services/trust/13/windowsmixed' for target 'https://adfs.domain.in/adfs/services/trust/13/windowsmixed' failed. See inner exception for more details.`

The inner error is:

`The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed.`
`NativeErrorCode:   0x80090350  -> SEC_E_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED`

I have tried /13/windows and /windowstransport as well as the endpoint.

```
private static GenericXmlSecurityToken RequestSecurityToken()
{
    // set up the ws-trust channel factory
    var factory = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory(new WindowsWSTrustBinding(
                SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://adfs.domain.in/adfs/services/trust/13/windowsmixed"), EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("adfs@domain.in")));
    factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
    var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
        KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
        AppliesTo = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(endpoint_address)
    };
    // request token and return
    return factory.CreateChannel().Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
}
```

Comment: SEC_E_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED means that a DC couldn't be contacted for granting you an authentication token.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane, you are right. I was about to answer this myself, in my case although the ADFS was available over VPN for a strange reason AD isnt. The other thing I noticed is if the code runs succesfully once without VPN then it works fine with VPN as well.